# Heroku filesystem

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

I am new in development world. I am trying to understand how the Heroku filesystem works.

I did an Express project using multer to upload images.

In production, everything worked well including fetching the images from my static folder.

However, when I did it with React (frontend=React & Backend=Express) the images are not displaying even though console shows no error.

According to my research Heroku says

> Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to the
>   filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is
>   shut down or restarted

and that I should use a dedicated file storage service such as AWS S3 (for static files).

How does this apply to my React project since I didn't use it  in the Express project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In production, everything worked well including fetching the images from my static folder.

In fact, it probably didn't.

Files can be saved to Heroku's ephemeral filesystem, and even loaded, but, as you have seen, [this isn't permanent](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts). Whenever your dyno restarts the filesystem resets. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day).

Express vs. React is irrelevant. You should *always* [use something like S3 for user uploads on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).